# Iterating over directories in Lua Torch

Tags: loops, for-loop, lua, iterator, torch

In Torch, I am iterating over a folder full of subfolders as follows:

```
subfolders = {}
counter = 0

for d in paths.iterdirs(root-directory) do
      counter = counter + 1
      subfolders[counter] = d
      -- do something with the subfolders' contents
end
```

When I print subfolders, the subfolders appear to have been accessed in a random order. Instead, want to iterate over them in name order. How do I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved using the following:

```
subfolders = {}
counter = 0

local dirs = paths.dir(root-directory)
table.sort(dirs)

for i = 1, 447 do
    counter = counter + 1
    subfolders[counter] = dirs[i]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed a more robust solution than Chris's answer, which doesn't exclude plain files, parent directories (`..`) or the current directory (`.`). I'm also not sure what the magic number `447` in his code is. [Standard Lua doesn't have a way to check if a file is a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833675/using-lua-check-if-file-is-a-directory), so this only works on Linux/OSX.

```
function isSubdir(path)
    noError, result = pcall(isDir, path)
    if noError then return result else return false end
end

-- Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3254007/1830334
function isDir(path)
    local f = io.open(path, 'r')
    local ok, err, code = f:read(1)
    f:close()
    return code == 21
end

function getSubdirs(rootDir)
    subdirs = {}
    counter = 0
    local dirs = paths.dir(rootDir)
    table.sort(dirs)
    for i = 1, #dirs do
        local dir = dirs[i]
        if dir ~= nil and dir ~= '.' and dir ~= '..' then
            local path = rootDir .. '/' .. dir
            if isSubdir(path) then
                counter = counter + 1
                subdirs[counter] = path
            end
        end
    end
    return subdirs
end

local subdirs = getSubdirs('/your/root/path/here')
print(subdirs)
```